# Why is EGARCH sensitive to scale?

Tags: r, data-transformation, garch

I recently estimated some OLS regressions with daily returns scaled by 100 as dependent variable (thus in percentage points). As I learned (and empirically confirmed), this scaling only scales coefficients by 100, but has no impact on statistical significance.

I used the same, scaled returns to estimate a simple EGARCH(1,1) model and found that the scaling directly impacts the coefficient for the unconditional variance `omega` and the significance of all other coefficients. The results are thus vastly different when using scaled data, especially when it comes to the interpretation of significance.

I used the SP500 data from the "rugarch" package in R and the `ugarchfit` function to produce following example:

Here with normal returns:

```
        Estimate  Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)  
mu      0.000670    0.000211     3.17900 0.001478               
ar1    -0.679036    0.017029   -39.87517 0.000000               
ma1     0.701977    0.016065    43.69611 0.000000               
omega  -0.269569    0.005428   -49.65921 0.000000               
alpha1 -0.197466    0.025594    -7.71537 0.000000               
alpha2  0.129236    0.005627    22.96744 0.000000               
beta1   0.970782    0.000080 12106.51240 0.000000               
gamma1 -0.009223    0.068496    -0.13465 0.892888               
gamma2  0.124195    0.055994     2.21802 0.026553               
shape   4.670759    0.848486     5.50481 0.000000                           
LogLikelihood : 3204.702
```

And here with returns scaled by 100:

```
        Estimate  Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)  
mu      0.067050    0.021114   3.175639 0.001495  
ar1    -0.679038    0.016626 -40.840967 0.000000  
ma1     0.701978    0.016644  42.176242 0.000000  
omega  -0.000460    0.006190  -0.074301 0.940771  
alpha1 -0.197462    0.060240  -3.277926 0.001046  
alpha2  0.129237    0.061149   2.113468 0.034561  
beta1   0.970786    0.003998 242.815325 0.000000  
gamma1 -0.009222    0.073792  -0.124977 0.900542  
gamma2  0.124189    0.075641   1.641818 0.100628  
shape   4.670628    0.881931   5.295909 0.000000  

LogLikelihood : -1400.468
```

Look especially at `omega` and the significance of `gamma2`!

Does anybody know why this is the case?

Comment: `omega` is not unconditional variance. It is associated with the level of the logarithm of the variance, but it is not the unconditional logged variance either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have estimated an ARMA(1,1)-EGARCH(2,1) rather than just an EGARCH(1,1). That gives you the following model equations:

$$\begin{aligned}
(r_t-\mu) &= \varphi_1 (r_{t-1}-\mu) + \varepsilon_t + \theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-1}; \\
\varepsilon_t &= \sigma_t u_t; \\
\ln(\sigma_t^2) &= \omega + \alpha_1(\varepsilon_{t-1}+\gamma_1(|\varepsilon_{t-1}|-\mathbb{E}\varepsilon_{t-1})) + \alpha_2(\varepsilon_{t-2}+\gamma_2(|\varepsilon_{t-2}|-\mathbb{E}\varepsilon_{t-2})) + \beta_1 \ln(\sigma_{t-1}^2); \\
u_t &\sim i.i.d(0,1). \\
\end{aligned}$$

In the estimation output, `ar1` stands for $\varphi_1$ and `ma1` for $\theta_1$.

When you scale the data by 100,

1. $\mu$ (the mean of $r_t$) and its standard error get scaled by 100;
2. $\omega$ (associated with the mean of $\ln(\sigma^2_t)$, but not equal to it) and its standard error get scaled by a nontrivial amount; arriving to a precise expression would involve some tedious arithmetics;
3. $\varphi_1$ and $\theta_1$ and their standard errors remain the same because they characterize the autoregressive behaviour which is independent of the level;
4. $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ and their standard errors remain the same analogously to 3.

These are analytical results. Meanwhile, empirical results may differ slightly. Optimization is involved in estimating the model parameters, which means the estimates are subject to rounding errors and probably convergence issues. As can be seen in your estimation output, the coefficients that are supposed to remain unchanged indeed remain roughly unchanged. However, some of their standard errors get affected considerably. My guess is, they suffer more from rouding errors because of being smaller. But it is a bit puzzling.

Comment: This does not offer a definite answer but hopefully will help understand the phenomenon better.